# Will this WCF client side code cause a memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, lambda

One of the frequent causes of memory leaks in .Net are event handlers which are never removed from their source objects.

Will this WCF code cause a memory leak, or will the lambda go out of scope too, allowing both the proxy class and the handler to be GCed?

```
void AMethod()
{
    WCFClient proxy;
    proxy = new WCFClient();
    proxy.RemoteOperationCompleted += (sender, e) => proxy.Close();
    proxy.Open();
    proxy.RemoteOperationAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my test - note the explicit `proxy` set to `null` in the lambda - without it the `WeakReference` lives and therefore a leak is likely:

```
public class Proxy
{
    private bool _isOpen;

    public event EventHandler Complete;

    public void Close() 
    {
        _isOpen = false;
    }

    public void Open() 
    { 
        _isOpen = true; 
    }

    public void RemoteOperationAsync()
    {
        if (!_isOpen)
            throw new ApplicationException();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (Complete != null)
            Complete(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WeakReference wr = null;

        {
            var proxy = new Proxy();
            proxy.Complete += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    proxy.Close();
                    wr = new WeakReference(proxy);
                    proxy = null;
                };
            proxy.Open();
            proxy.RemoteOperationAsync();
        }

        GC.Collect(GC.GetGeneration(wr));
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine("[LAMBDA] Is WeakReference alive? " + wr.IsAlive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it because the current method scope hasn't been unwind yet (so GC won't clean them)? Put them in a method, `GC.Collect` and check the wr as a field in Main. It's not alive without `proxy = null`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the proxy's don't correctly implement IDisposable.  If an error occurs the code above will not clean up the connection and the handle will remain until the parent process is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The context where the lamdba is defined will be captured and will therefore "survive" in the compiler created closure class (you can see them with Reflector) - so your proxy too. Use weak event handler or write code for unregistration. But in that case you can't use lambda expression.

Answer (score -1):

That object will die... it'll be cleaned up.

Don't forget that the lamda isn't doing anything special... it's a compiler trick (so just assume it's a normal += SomeDelegate).

Also, the "Close" method (I don't know why they didn't make it IDisposable) will clean up everything else that was left open.